# how to redirect select tag value from view to controller and then to view without reloding in codeigniter with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

i want to send my select tag value to my controller from view and controller will pass message to the same view without reloading the page and will not change the select tag option value what i have selected already.i used ajax but it didn't work to redirect from view to controller and again to view.i want to use the concept that when i select a value within a select tag ,the value will be passed to conroller and get the correspondin data from database and assign it to the next select tag without reloding the page and not changing my another select tag's selected  content.but i have failed due that reason.what can i do now?i am not handling database section now.here is my code.it is view page **test1.php**

```
<body>
    <?php
    echo "selected: " . $x;
    echo "<br>";
    ?>
    <label> Movie Name :</label>
    <select class="mv_name">
        <option value="select">Select</option>
        <option value="Elysium">Elysium</option>
        <option value="Out of the Furnace">Out of the Furnace</option>
        <option value="American Hustle">American Hustle</option>
        <option value="The Hobbit">The Hobbit</option>
        <option value="Frozen">Frozen</option>
        <option value="Despicable Me 2">Despicable Me 2</option>
    </select>
    <label> Quantity :</label>
    <select class="quantity">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="">1</option>
        <option value="">2</option>
        <option value="">3</option>
        <option value="">4</option>
        <option value="">5</option>
        <option value="">6</option>
    </select>

    <script>
        $('.mv_name').on('change', function() {
            alert(this.value);
            var form_data = {
                select_value: this.value,
                ajax: '1'
            };

            $.ajax({
                url: "<?php echo base_url('test1_c/redirect1'); ?>",
                type: 'POST',
                data: form_data,
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function(msg) {
                    alert(msg);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>

</body>
```

my controller **test1_c.php**

```
<?php

class Test1_c extends CI_Controller {

    public function index() {
        $data['x'] = "intial value";
        $this->load->view('test1', $data);
    }

    function redirect1() {
        echo "redirect";
        $is_ajax = $this->input->post('ajax');

        if ($is_ajax) {
            $data['x'] = $this->input->post('select_value');

            $this->load->view('test1', $data);
        }
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: Use $(this).val() and not this.value in order to access the value of the select element

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you wish to get the user's selection from a selection box and then send back information to the user.

It cannot be done without sending a new request, however, consider this little 'trick' based on form validation of code igniter.

in a controller you assign the POST value of a select.
for example,

```
$this->select = $_POST['selectionbox']
$this->value[$this->select] = $this->select ;
```

so what is this good for? you now have a variable called value that holds a key/value pair with the name of the **option** of the select box.

moving on, you create a simple function that checks if a variable exists, else return "";

```
function returnPost($value)
{
if isset( $this->value($value))
$temp = "select="selected"
return  $temp;
}
```

Moving on once more, You can now use that function in your view itself, for example:

```
<select>
<option value="test" <?php returnPost('test') ?> > test </option>
<option value="fail" <?php returnPost('fail') ?> > fail</option>
</select>
```

now what this does is this

1)user hits submit, we save the value of the select to a variable.
2)when we load the view, we use a function to check if this specific select exists, if it does, we echo the select=selected attribute, if it's not we do no nothing.

and that's it basically :)
Do note - this is indeed a brand new request and it only seems like the page isn't reloading, it in fact does reload.